# Automatize Integration Services Project Password for Visual Studio Solution

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, visual-studio-project

I have a Visual Studio solution with multiple projects and they use the protection level: "Encrypt sensitive with password", **so every time that the solution is loaded I have to enter the password manually for each project.**

**There's a way to automatize this?** passing the password via command line when I open the solution or something like that?

The password is the same for all projects.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better just to disable the encryption then?

Comment: http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: SSIS Projects have two main methods for storing sensitive data on projects and packages (like Connection string passwords): 
1 - Encrypt Sensitive with User Key 
2 - Encrypt Sensitive with Password

I'm using the second, because we are a team of developers that are working with the same Solution and the User Key is exclusive for each developer machine. 

If I remove the encryption, sensitive data will be not saved in the projects.

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Studio application is called `devenv.exe` *(SQL Server Data Tools is included)*, And according to [MSDN - Devenv Command Line Switches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx), there is no command line that can be used to achieve your goal. Simply disable the encryption if it is disturbing you.